# Can I import Java class files into JRuby?

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

The documentation seems to suggest that in order for me to import Java classes into JRuby, that they must be in a JAR file:

"In order to use resources within a jar file from JRuby the jar file must either be on the classpath or you can make it available with the require method"
(http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Calling_Java_from_JRuby#Require_a_jar_file_to_make_resources_in_the_jar_discoverable_within_JRuby)

Is it at all possible to import .class files directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to answer my own question :)

If your class files are compiled to a relative path of "target", e.g. foo.Bar is located in "target/foo/Bar.class", then you do the following:

```
require 'java'
require 'target/foo/Bar'

module Foo
  include_package 'foo'
end

puts Foo::Bar.new
```

And the result:

```
foo.Bar@1582a7c
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you could also:

```
require 'java'
$CLASSPATH << "target"
```

and then

```
foo.bar.baz.Class.new() # ... 
# or 
java_import 'foo.bar.baz.Class'
```

Comment: $CLASSPATH instead of $CLASS_PATH